# A little lost with grub and mbr : Formatting the partition that has boot flag?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mbr

I plan on doing something stupid. Therefore, I need to take all necessary precautions to make it less stupid. As always with those very low level operations, I'm very far from being an expert and may have caused problems along the way, so I will describe the whole story.

------First, here is the setup-----

I have a laptop with a single 512Gb SSD. This laptop was installed with an encrypted Windows 7 that I had access to. In order for me to work, I had to use linux and a VM was out of the question for several reasons. Therefore I decided to install a dual boot on this machine. From Windows OS, I shrinked the size of the partition into two chunks : ~350Gb for the Windows partition and ~160 Gb for the linux one. As I was expecting some problem with the Windows boot (especially because it was an encrypted partition of the whole disk), I saved the mbr (actually the safeboot mbr, which itself links to the actual encrypted mbr of windows) into a mbr.img file.

After installing linux on the remaining space, I lost access to my Windows partition (as expected) and could boot up linux. In my grub.cfg file, I added an entry

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"{
  insmod ntfs
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  set mbr_file="/boot/mbr_safeboot.img"
  chainloader (hd0,5)$mbr_file
}
```

This entry was going to check in on my linux partition /dev/sda5 the /boot/mbr_safeboot.img and load it directly, thus linking to the encrpted windows mbr, and allowed me to boot windows correctly. Yay.

Fast forward a few months, I am in a conference just before a presentation and windows decides to do an update. Of course, it asks me to reboot. And of course, for some reason, it messed up the Windows boot.

Right now, my disk is set up as :

```
/dev/sda1 : boot flag and mbr alongside with the encrypted, unbootable NTFS partition
/dev/sda2 : Extended partition
/dev/sda5 : EXT4 : 50Gb  /
/sev/sda6 : Swap : 8Gb 
/dev/sda6 : EXT4 : 100Gb /home
```

---- What I would like to do -----

I don't care about the Windows partition. Of course, I will do an image of this partition just in case that I will save somewhere but right now, it's dead space. I want to remove it to be able to use the space.

The reason I said that I was planning to do something stupid is that ... this /dev/sda1 is the partition that holds the mbr ! I understand very well that formatting that part is not really wise.

What I was originally planning on doing  :

1. Save the current mbr and partition table
2. Format /dev/sda1
3. Restore or repair the mbr using a linux live-cd

My questions are the following :

1. Is it the best course of action ?
2. Would it be possible to format /dev/sda1 without touching the MBR ?
3. What additional steps should I include in order to reduce the risks of messing up anything ?

Thanks for your inputs guys !

Comment: *"/dev/sda1 is the partition that holds the mbr"* - This is incorrect. The MBR is the first 512 bytes on the disk. It is not in a partition.

Comment: *"Would it be possible to format /dev/sda1 without touching the MBR?"* - Yes, as long as you really mean the MBR.

Comment: As I mentionned in the initial part of my description : I am far from being an expert and it shows !

I may have gotten a little confused then ... I thought the "boot flag" (the little star) from fdisk -l was indicative of the place where the MBR is located, is it wrong ? 

If it is, then what is it ? Because it would mean that I have : the mbr in the first 512 bytes of the disk (which is not a partition as you mentioned), a /boot folder that contains the grub.cfg files, and something ELSE on /dev/sda1 ?

Comment: See this answer on what boot flags are: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23588

Comment: And unless you created a separate `/boot` partition, `/boot` resides in your main EXT4 partition.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, my /boot is in my main EXT4 partition (http://pastie.org/10946753)

Do you think I should take any more appropriate measure other than saving the mbr/partition table before formatting the /dev/sda1 ?

Comment: Anyone who attempts "fixing" a disk without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.